# Multiple TextEdit in a form in qml

Tags: c++, qml

Let's say I want to build a page with a form. When I click on a form, I want to open a keyboard.
I also want to condition the validation of the form with some validation

Here is an example (pseudo code)

```
Item {
    Keyboard{id: keyboard}

    Column {
        TextEdit {
            id: nameEdit
            onClicked: keyboard.open()
            onTextChanged: checkIfOk()
        }
        TextEdit {
            id: userName
            onClicked: keyboard.open()
            onTextChanged: checkIfOk()
        }
        TextEdit {
            id: password
            onClicked: keyboard.open()
            onTextChanged: checkIfOk()
        }
    }

    function checkIfOk() {
        buttonOk.enabled = password.text.length > 0 &&
                           userName.text.length > 0 &&
                           nameEdit.text.length > 0
    }

    Button {
        id: buttonOk

        onClicked {
            userBackend.createUser({.name: nameEdit.text,
                                    .userName: userName.text,
                                    .pwd: password.text}
        }
    }
}
```

So, I tried to factorize it with a repeater like:

```cpp
Item {
    Keyboard{id: keyboard}

    Column {
        id: column
        Repeater {
             model: 3
             TextEdit{}
        }
    }

    Button {
        id: buttonOk
        enabled: //??
    }

}
```

But how can I get properties of the children in a clean way and bind their result to a property ?

Is fetching items from `children` the only and better way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [itemAt](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-repeater.html#itemAt-method) function of Repeater. Online qml coding app does not respond at the moment, so I coldn't try it. Hope it works.

```
Item {
    Column {
        id: column
        
        Repeater {
            id: textEditRepeater
            model: 3
            
            TextEdit {
                onTextChanged: checkIfOk()
            }
        }
    }

    function checkIfOk() {
        for (int i = 0; i < textEditRepeater.count; ++i) {
            var item = textEditRepeater.itemAt(i);
            
            if (item === null || item.text.length === 0) {
                buttonOk.enabled = false;
                return;
            }
        }
        
        buttonOk.enabled = true;
    }

    Button {
        id: buttonOk
        enabled: false
    }
}
```